# WCF: Pass json as parameter

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf

Suppose I have the follow json:

```
{
    "id": 8574,
    "data": {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 24,
        "description": "test",
        "anotherjson": { "fielda": "valuea", "fieldb": "valueb" }
    }
}
```

Important: I don't know what are the fields in data parameter.

And I have the follow method:

```
public void Save(int id, object data) { ... }
```

The json is sent by jQuery.ajax() to the method.

If I put this method in a asp.net web service (.asmx), I can convert the data parameter to Dictionary[string, object]. It's good.

But if I put this method in a WCF service, the data parameter is always empty.

What I have to do? I need the same behavior in WCF as in .asmx files.

Answer (score 0):

have you added the below attribute in thr WCF method?

```
[OperationContract]
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void Save(int id, object data) { ... }
```

and your service with the below attribute

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode 
    = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class Service : IService
  {....}
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, i did. The WCF is running fine. My only problem are the parameters with json content.